# Can I use the Python package Bokeh to put a network graph from networkx on top of a geographic map?

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh

I know that Bokeh has networkx integration, but I was uncertain if you could then put this network graph on top of a geographic map. The network graph in mind has nodes that are connected by edges, in this case interactions between the two nodes.

I can create the network graph and geographic map separately on Bokeh, but am uncertain of how I could put them together.

Comment: HoloViews.org makes it simple to overlay any two plots sharing the same dimensions, generating Bokeh plot output. Not sure how to do it with Bokeh's own API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.